# Sub-Table and complex head markups

Tags: java, richfaces, vaadin, vaadin7

Until now I used RichFaces like web-framework to build presentation layer to some applications, now at company I work for has been decided to some project to use vaadin instead of richfaces. With richFaces when I had complex table-based data representations, I often use:

> rich:collapsibleSubTable

to get components that looks like at the following

[image]

Now I want to ask you how can i get a similar result with vaadin?

Are there some add-on to make it?Otherwise can you give me some suggestion about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the [table](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.table.html) you can go with the one from vaadin

for the folding you could use a [tree](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/components.tree.html) on the left side of the table in a horizontal layout or you could go with an [accordion](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.accordion.html) or with [tabsheet](https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin7/-/page/layout.tabsheet.html) and put the table for each continent there.

accordion + table would come closest to what you have there with least efford.